# get the indexes of the N largest values in a list such that these values respect a given condition

Tags: python

```
Ids = [ i for i, v in heapq.nlargest(RN, enumerate(score_real_test), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

This will give the indexes of the RN largest values in list score_real_test. Is it instead possible to get the indexes of the RN largest values that "are in list score_real_test and satisfy a boolean condition COND" ?

Ids should contains RN indexes.

EDIT: for now I use this solution but it is not the best one :

```
score_real_test_2 = np.sort( [ v for i,v in enumerate(score_real_test) if pred_real_test[i] == NOVEL ] )
score_real_test_2 = score_real_test_2[len(score_real_test_2)-RN:]
large_dist_ids = [i for i in range(len(score_real_test)) if score_real_test[i] in score_real_test_2]
```

Comment: can you mention your doubt clearly?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh what do you not understand in my question ? I want to add a condition to the N large values that I choose, for instance if indexe i satisfy A_Given_List[i] == true, then I'll take it into account if it is among the N largest values, otherwise, I'll not consider i. Is this clear ?

Comment: In general, you can add an if statement in your list comprehension.  For example: `[i for i in myList]` -> `[i for i in myList if (i%2)]`.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @jedwards no, if you add if statement at the end, you will not get N indexes at the end, you'll get less than N coz you will filter out those which do not respect the condition, but in my case I want to get N values (N indexes of the largest values that respect the condition witch is a function of i)

Comment: [ i for i, v in heapq.nlargest(N, enumerate(score_real_test), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) if (i%2)] will give you less than N indexes of the largest elements from score_real_test that respect (i%2)

Comment: Well I think that we should not use heapq in this case, I guess that I should sort the list score_real_test, then take the values from right to left if they respect the condition, untill I get N values ..

EDIT: Oh but if I do that I'll loose the position of values in the list since it will be sorted ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this is a one-liner, you can simply replace enumerate by a list comprehension(or generator expression) that pre-filters your data based on the condition.

Like so:

```
Ids = [i for i, v in heapq.nlargest(RN, [(j,v) in enumerate(score_real_test) if pred_real_test[i] == NOVEL], key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

Or if you want to keep it clearer, you can add a filtering step before the selection(still no need for pre-sorting):

```
tmp = [item for item in enumerate(score_real_test) if pred_real_test[item[0]] == NOVEL]
Ids = [i for i, v in heapq.nlargest(RN, tmp, key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

Comment: Ids would be the indexes of elements in enumerate(tmp) or those of elements in score_real_test ?

Comment: Ah, you're right, it would be wrong indexes, but that is easy to rectify. I'll edit to reflect.

Comment: Yes, I did. Try the code and see if it gives you the correct results if you're unsure. Let me know if you find any problems.